# Almost Convex Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I am having a hard time understanding what almost convex means. The definition is the following:

A group $G = \langle S\rangle$ is almost convex if there exists a constant $k$ such that every two points in the sphere of radius $n$ at distance at most 2 in the Cayley graph $\Gamma(G,S)$ can be joined by a path of length at most $k$ that stays in the radius ball of lenght $n$.

I am also having a difficult time trying to solve this question: Let $G$ and $H$ be almost convex groups, show that $G \bigoplus H$ and $G * H$ are also almost convex groups.

Comment: So, what do you know about almost convex groups? Do you know the definition?

Comment: I Suggest you that you read chapter seven from Geometric group theory, an introduction by Clara Loh

Comment: I do not understand the definition.

Comment: I think the question was not whether you understand the definition (you already said in the question that you don't) but whether you know it.

Comment: @joriki has it right - maybe if you produce the definition someone will be able to help you understand and/or use it.

Comment: I have the definition. A group is almost convex if it has a cayley graph that is almost convex. A cayley graph is almost convex if whenever two vertices on the sphere of radius n can be joined by a path </ 2 in the cayley graph and then they can be joined by a pair of length </ K that stays inside the ball of radius n. The balls are the balls in the cayley graph.

Comment: I thank you, and I apologize, as now that I see the definition, I, too, am having a hard time understanding what it means. Maybe the way to understand the definition is to look at a few examples of groups that are almost convex, and a few examples of groups that aren't, and get a feeling for the definition that way.

Comment: @ Gerry. I did a few examples and it made me understand the definition a little more. My problem is figuring out how to prove the direct sum of two almost convex groups is almost convex. Its driving me crazy. I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Being almost convex means that balls in the Catkey graph don't have 'horns', i.e. long subsets that almost touch each other at the tips (spare close in the Cayley graph) but are far apart traveling in the ball. If someone folded the Earth (like Inception) so that Shanghai was only a mile in the air above London, the cities would be close (a mile apart), but if one is restricted to walking on the surface of the earth, the distance is very long.

For the second part, just change each coordinate one at a time. It won't make you leave the ball.